# Why is my NN model's prediciton for y= sinc(x) function showing symmetric?

Tags: neural-network, machine-learning-model, pytorch, training, prediction

```py
# Generate noisy data
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 500)
y_true = np.sinc(x)

# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
x_tensor = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
y_tensor = torch.tensor(y_true, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)

x_data = x[0:240:5]
y_data = y_true[0:240:5]
x_data_tensor = torch.tensor(x_data, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)
y_data_tensor = torch.tensor(y_data, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(1)


torch.manual_seed(123)  
class SincNet2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SincNet2, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 55)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(55, 55)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(55, 55)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(55, 55)  # Additional hidden layer
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(55, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sin(x) / x
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc4(x))  # Apply activation to the output of the additional hidden layer
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x
model2 = SincNet2()
optimizer2 = torch.optim.Adam(model2.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
criterion = nn.MSELoss() 
# Train  models
losses = [] # to store loss 

num_epochs = 2000                      
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Forward pass
    y_ptrain = model2(x_data_tensor)
    loss = criterion(y_ptrain, y_data_tensor)

    # Backward and optimize
    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer2.step()

    if (epoch+1) % 100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
        
        
    losses.append(loss.item())


# Generate predictions on original x data
with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred= model2(x_tensor) # Use squeeze() to remove the singleton dimension
    
    
# Store losses in a file
with open('losses_sinc.txt', 'w') as f:
    for epoch, loss in enumerate(losses):
        f.write(f"Epoch {epoch+1}: {loss}\n")
        
        
# Plot the original data, training data, and predicted curve on training and original x data
plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.ylim(-0.5, 1.3)

plt.plot(x, y_true, color='b', label='True Function', linewidth=2)
plt.scatter(x_data, y_ptrain.detach().numpy(), color='r', label='Predicted Curve (Training Data)', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y_pred.detach().numpy(), color='g', label='Predicted Curve (Original x Data)', linewidth=2)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('sincx')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('sinc_nn_prediction.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi @RimaMonica, welcome to the site. It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why your model has learned a symetric function while you have only trained it with data on the negative x axis? Please, include more information, like the plot obtained with your code, what you expected to get, and why what you got is unexpected to you.

Comment: I generated 500 synthetic data for the function, y=sinc(x) and took 240 data points from the LHS or negative side as train data. After training NN, it is natural to expect to see the prediction on the negative side and with a bit of generalization with unseen data. However, my NN predicts okay for train data then after a random prediction with unseen data, it predicted from the positive side or RHS data and it looks like mirroring the prediction of LHS data which is unexpected. why on the right side it's mirroring the prediction like LHS data when I did not use it for training data at all?

Comment: Please do not post additional info in the comments - edit & update your post instead (where this info should have been included in the first place, instead of just a piece of code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is symmetric because the first thing you do in the forward pass is this:

```
x = torch.sin(x) / x
```

$\sin(x)/x$ is symmetric so, after that, any further computations will not depend on the original sign of $x$.